# How do I include calendar items in my Outlook 2013 To-Do List?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, to-do

Outlook 2013 has a nice To-Do-List that aggregates all of your tasks and any flagged messages, then groups them by due date.  It seems a little odd that it doesn't also include your calendar items.

Is there a way I can add calendar items to the To-Do List either automatically or manually?  Replicating every calendar item as a task is not a suitable solution.